# Randomly select three groups with equal means

Tags: experiment-design, biostatistics

I am looking for a method which I can randomly select 100 subjects from each of 3 populations so that each selected group has equal mean body weights. The population data I will be selecting from will include three separate populations of 200 or more baby pigs with individual body weights for each pig. Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Solutions do not necessarily exist, as you can easily see by considering smaller versions of this problem, such as $3$ subjects with $3$ different weights. Moreover, even when there are solutions, asking for *exact* equality of means is such a severe restriction that the "randomness" is anything but that and becomes useless for (correct) statistical analysis.  This all suggests you might be trying to solve a problem you haven't yet stated, but what is it?  What is the statistical purpose of this selection and what objective would be served by the equal-mean restriction?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The hypothesis I would like to test is "baby with optimal hemoglobin status at weaning will grow faster post-weaning than baby pigs with sub-clinical or deficient hemoglobin". The statistical purpose of this selection would be to start with statistically similar mean weights among the three hemoglobin groups at the start of the test. If there are significantly different mean weights to start with, it could be possible that starting weight influenced post-weaning growth and not hemoglobin concentration.